# View models in a browser

Tags: browser, viewer, 3ds

Is there a way to view models in a browser via flash, Java or anything else?

The models would be stored on my server with the client viewing it along with textures and anything else the model would need.

I would like any browser app that works ideally with 3ds.

Comment: Viewing models in the browser? I do that all the time... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

VRML is mostly dead, but you might still be able to find a browser plugin for it. This page leads to some newer 3D web technologies: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vrml

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

http://blog.promethe.net/2008/12/24/display-half-life-3d-models-with-flash-10/

It mentions something called [DirectFlex](http://blog.directflex.net/what-is-directflex/) as well, which I haven't used personally, but at any rate, either of these links might point you in the right direction with respect to using Flash 10 to display your models.  Hope it helps!